# How do I insert image

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I insert image in my python-tkinter project?
I wanted to insert image in my tkinter Button, I tried it with this code:

```
photo = PhotoImage(r"Link to folder containing image\image.png")
photoimage = photo.subsample(3,3) # because I want image+text in button
st = Button(root, text='Sample', bg='grey', width=15, height=7, command=callback , image = photoimage, compound= LEFT, font=('Comic Sans Ms',20,'italic'))
st.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20, side = TOP)
```

but this code dosen't work, I am using SubLime Text 3 IDE to build my projects

Comment: Could you please give a few more details as to what doesn't work? does the image not show up? is there an error?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Is it throwing an error? If so, what's the error?

Comment: when I run my program it says: couldn't recognize the data in image file, even after I am using png image file

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you need:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1.Files/UI/edit.png")
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in the file path. Try escaping it. that means that you have to put two backslashes in a row instead of one when you're writing the path because it thinks that you're trying to escape a special character. you also need to make sure that you pass the path to the `file` parameter by typing `file=` before the path.

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="Link to folder containing image\\image.png")
```

Comment: Let me tell you what I had already tried: First I added the folder containing the image file to my sublime text from Projects tab and then I tried '''photo = PhotoImage(file=icons/Sample.png')''' and I also tried as you told in your answer but still getting the same error, to check that if there is any problem with my image file, I also tried inserting another .png image but it was also of no help

Comment: Well, the problem might be with the `photo.subsample()` thing, but I'm not sure. I'm not really familiar with that.

Answer (score -1):

If the button isn't showing up altogether, then you might have forgotten to pack the Button. Try adding `.pack(side=TOP)` at the end of the line where you define the button (`st = Button(...).pack(side=TOP)`)

This worked for me.

Comment: The code n the question shows that they are already calling `grid` on the button.

Comment: @Bhavye Mathur                                                                                                                                 I also tried with pack geometry manager but it was of no help, getting same error "couldn't recognize the data in image file

Comment: hmmm... this did solve the issue for me even when I had the grid function below. But I'll try trying something else.

Comment: when I write '''photo= PhotoImage(file='star.gif')
photo=photo.subsample(4,4)
st=Button(tab1, text='OK', width=100, height=70, image=photo, compound= LEFT)
st.pack(pady=20, side=LEFT) then my image appears but it's not in the left side of button it covers the entire button instead of image the button appears on left side of window